# Gesture detector in Single Child Scroll View to detect onTouchDown and onTouchUp

Tags: flutter

I am currently putting a gesture detector to detect the touch down and touch up action in a single child scroll view. However, the scroll view seems to make the detection delayed if the scroll view contains enough elements that makes it perform scroll action. The following url provides the sample code for this issue.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child; Column (
    children: [
      Container (
        width: 200,
        height: 1000,
      ),
      GestureDetector(
    onTapUp: (value) {
      print('tap up');
      isTap = false;
      setState(() {});
    },
    onTapDown: (value) {
      print('tap Down');
      isTap = true;
      setState(() {});
    },
    child: Container(
        color: isTap ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        child: const Text("HELLO")));
    ]
  )
)
```

This is the url for the complete code
https://codeshare.io/Lw8vl6

Comment: can you try to run in profile mode, I am not getting any performance issue, Can you include the issue and expected output as gif

Comment: Lets say, if I print tapDown whenever onTapDown detected and print tapUp whenever onTapUp detected. I need to tap the button and hold it with around 0.5 second to let it trigger the onTapDown and onTapUp function. But if I simply use onTap, it can detect the action immediately

Comment: If you still don't get what I mean, I can provide a gif later on, thanks

Comment: In my test snippet, you can try creating separate widget and test it,  I don't need to hold, btw are you trying to archive hover effect?

Comment: I have just edited the post, I need to hold in a real device or simulator, but in dart pad I don't need to hold

Comment: I've tested on chrome cant produce any issue, yes it might be laggy on debug depend on device config, Can you build the app and then test it on your real device.

Comment: Yup, I have tested it in both real device and simulator, which result the same, having delay

Comment: Updated the question again, coz I finally spot the root cause of this issue

Comment: OK the issue come when we hold the gesture detector and try to scroll am i right

Comment: I think the issue is when we touch down the gesture detector, the scroll action is fired, so the touch down detection delayed. You can try it by removing the container, and press the gesture detector again. It is my expected performance.

Comment: I expect the print message will appear immediately when I touch down the gesture detector, but it delayed for around 0.5 seconds